# How many shapes are possible from gluing together the faces of n cubes?

Tags: permutations, combinatorial-geometry

Say I have *n* cubes. I am allowed to glue the faces of these cubes together, but the faces must line up perfectly. How many unique shapes could I make? All orientations of one shape are considered to be the same shape.

I'm doing an engineering assignment where I must draw the different possible shapes, but I'm curious as to what the mathematical formula is to determine the maximum number of shapes.

Comment: Considering the complexity of [two-dimensional polyominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino), I doubt the answer to your question is known. The wikipedia page on [polycubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycube) is brief, suggesting not much is known.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193689/how-many-shapes-can-one-make-with-n-square-shaped-blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open problem; no general formula is known.  The shapes are called "polycubes".

However, the values are known for small $n$; you can find them listed up to $n=16$ the in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=Polycubes&sort=&language=english&go=Search).

Note that there are two sets of answers, depending on whether you consider two polycubes to be [the same](http://oeis.org/A038119), or [different](http://oeis.org/A000162), when they are mirror images of one another.