# Constructing blocks from $n$ square blocks of size $1\times 1$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

> Given $n$ square blocks of size $1\times 1$, how many blocks up to rotation and reflection are possible to construct if we paste all of them together side to side $($ let's call it $\, B(n) \, )$ . For example, $B(1)=B(2)=1$, $B(3)=2$ and $B(4)=5$.
>
> [image]

The problem is simple for small values of $n$, but for higher values the complexity increases drastically, I believe that there is some kind of relation between $B(n)$ and the partitions of an integer $n$. It took me some time to calculate $B(5)$, as there are several possibilities. I am not sure whether the figure below contains all possible blocks for $n=5$. I don't see any pattern here. How do we find $B(n)$ for any natural number $n$?

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193689/how-many-shapes-can-one-make-with-n-square-shaped-blocks

Comment: glimpse at https://home.adelphi.edu/~stemkoski/mathematrix/polys.html

Answer (score 1):

For $n=5$ their number is $12$. You missed $2$ of them:
[image]

For more details see [free polyominoes](https://oeis.org/A000105). There is no known formula for the number of distinct polyominoes of a given number of squares.

Comment: Thank you robert. For a general $n$, is it possible to find $B(n)$ ?

Comment: There is no known formula for the number of distinct polyominoes of a given number of squares.